# Error when running sudo apt-get upgrade

Tags: pi-3

Using a Pi 3

If I run `sudo apt-get upgrade`, I get this result:

```
W: Unable to read /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/ - DirectoryExists (2: No such file or directory)
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (2: No such file or directory)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

Here is the output of `uname -a`:

```
Linux raspberrypi 4.4.26-v7+ #915 SMP Thu Oct 20 17:08:44 BST 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

And here is the output of `cat /etc/os-release`:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

What is causing the error?

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the output of `uname -a` and `cat /etc/os-release`?

Comment: What ist the output of `ls /; ls /etc; ls /etc/apt; ls /etc/apt/apt.conf.d; ls /var; ls /var/lib; ls /var/lib/dpkg` ?

Comment: ls: cannot access /var/lib/dpkg: No such file or directory

ls: cannot access /etc/apt: No such file or directory

ls: cannot access /etc/apt/apt.conf.d: No such file or directory

Comment: Sorry, but you have a bad disk. This is basically data corruption and there is little you can do to fix it.

Also, before doing `apt-get upgrade` you must first execute `apt-get update`

Comment: I think that the problem is with odoo image. using odoo image, i think that it's not possible to use sudo command